# Iterate each textbox controls in "MainContents"?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, textbox, iteration, web-controls

I'm able to iterate each text box control in "MainContents" by using the code below.
Q1: Is there a shorter way? (to get all controls in "MainContents"?)

```
    For Each ctrl As Control In Page.Controls
        For Each subctrl As Control In ctrl.Controls
            For Each subctrlsub As Control In subctrl.Controls
                If TypeOf subctrlsub Is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder Then
                    If subctrlsub.ClientID = "MainContent" Then
                        For Each ct As Control In subctrlsub.Controls
                            If TypeOf ct Is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox Then
                                For r As Short = 1 To 8
                                    For c As Short = 1 To 6
                                        .... (do something) ...
                                    Next
                                Next
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted this from C# to VB, forgive the potential incorrectness.  This is called Recursion.

```
Protected Sub DoSomething(ctrl As Control)
   For Each c As Control In ctrl.Controls
       If TypeOf c Is ContentPlaceHolder Then
          If c.ClientID = "MainContent" Then
                           // Do your stuff
          End If
       End If

       If c.Controls.Count > 0 Then
          DoSomething(c)
       End If
   Next
End Sub
```